# How to use Guava Optional as "naturally covariant object"

Tags: generics, guava, covariance

The new Guava 10 [Optional](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html)  states to be naturally covariant and thus may be casted.

If I try so it looks a bit ugly:

```
Optional<Integer> opti = Optional.of(42);
Optional<Number>  optn =  (Optional) opti;
```

I like to see some utility function like:

```
static <T> Optional<T> transform(Optional<? extends T> opt, Class<T> clazz);
```

(how to express this as a member function of Optional ?)

Is it even possible to define a transformation function object like:

```
static <T> Function<Optional<? extends T>, Optional<T>> 
transformer(Class<T> class);
```

in order to transform a `Collection<Optional<Double>>` into a `Collection<Optional<Number>>` without creating new objects for each?

I think even the returned Function object may be realized by an internal singleton.

Answer (score 8):

Even though casting is actually *even uglier* than you think:

```
Optional<Integer> opti = Optional.of(42);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // safe covariant cast
Optional<Number> optn = (Optional) opti;
```

... we still think it is exactly what you should do, and have ruled out providing a method like you ask for.

It's okay that it's a little cumbersome because you should *very rarely* need to do a thing like this, so long as you are using wildcards correctly in your API signatures, as covered in *Effective Java.*

Answer (score 8):

By specifying the type of the `of` method, you can avoid the cast entirely:

```
        Optional<Number> optx = Optional.<Number>of(42);
```

Comment: No need for the ugly type parameter: `Optional.of((Number) 42);`