# Contravariantly converting Guava Predicates

Tags: java, generics, guava, contravariance

I have a `Predicate<Object>` and need an equivalent `Predicate<Animal>`.

```
Predicate<Animal> provideIsSentientPredicate() {
    // Won't compile -- cannot convert from Predicate<Object> to Predicate<Animal>
    return Predicates.instanceOf(Human.class);
}
```

Predicates are contravariant, so converting a `Predicate<Object>` to a `Predicate<Animal>` is safe.  Is there clean and readable way to convert from a `Predicate<Object>` to a `Predicate<Animal>` (e.g. without suppressing warnings)?

I'd prefer not to change my method's type signature to return a `Predicate<? super Animal>` or `Predicate<Object>` unless someone convinces me that is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Related question for Optional: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848789/how-to-use-guava-optional-as-naturally-covariant-object

Comment: The type of `Predicates.instanceOf` is absolutely intended to push you to either return a `Predicate<? super Animal>`, or to return `Predicate<Object>` and change the caller to expect a `Predicate<? super Animal>`.

Comment: @Louis Wow!  Really?  That wasn't my expectation at all!  I've always thought it was rude to make a client deal with a wildcard type and so I've never written a method with a wildcard return type.  Are wildcard return types ever considered good practice?  I can't recall any method in the Guava source tree that returns a wildcard type -- is there one?

Comment: I don't have a serious preference one way or the other, but if you dislike returning wildcard types, then it's totally legit to return `Predicate<Object>` and force the client to _consume_ it as a `Predicate<? super Animal>`.  Types are weird.

Comment: Okay, I've been convinced that the examples from `Predicates` as how they want you to use it: return specific types, even if they're more general than necessary, and _consume_ `Predicate<? super Foo>`.

Comment: @Louis So, in this case, return the specific type `Predicate<Animal>`?

Comment: No, return `Predicate<Object>`, and change the calling code to treat it as a `Predicate<? super Animal>`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28682/discussion-between-robert-cooper-and-louis-wasserman)

Answer (score 4):

```
Predicate<Animal> provideIsSentientPredicate() 
{
    return cast( Predicates.instanceOf(Human.class) );
}

static <A, B extends A> Predicate<B> cast(Predicate<A> pa)
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    Predicate<B> pb = (Predicate)(pa);
    return pb;

    // we know it works correctly in practice.
    // or if you are a theorist, create a wrapper predicate
    //
    //     Predicate<B>
    //         boolean apply(B b)
    //             return pa.apply(b);
}
```

BTW, there's no reason why Guava shouldn't declare the method as

```
static <T> Predicate<T> instanceOf(Class<?> clazz)
```

consistent with other sibling methods.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't figure out why it isn't `static <T> Predicate<T> instanceOf(Class<?> clazz)` either, but the Guava team usually has good (if subtle) reasons for this sort of thing.  Guava avoids generics in other static factory methods (`Ordering.allEqual()`, `Ordering.arbitrary()`, `Ordering.usingToString()`), and @Louis comment seems to suggest that `Predicates.instanceOf()`'s return type is intentional.  Still no clue why, though.

Comment: In reply to my previous comment, I would guess the most likely reasons the method signature of `Predicate<Object> instanceOf(Class<?> clazz)` isn't `static <T> Predicate<T> instanceOf(Class<?> clazz)` is that second signature is more complicated, is harder to test, is harder to read, is less forward compatible, and doesn't hold advantages over the first signature in enough cases to make the switch.  BUT, if there's a deeper reason than that, I would really be curious to hear it.